# Is it possible to use the data of a String array to access the number of the element?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Lets say we have a string array.

```
String [] typicalStringArray = new String[3];
typicalStringArray[0] = "apple";
typicalStringArray[1] = "banana";
typicalStringArray[2] = "pineapple";
String chosenFruit = typicalStringArray[0];
System.out.println(chosenFruit);
```

Is it possible to do the same thing backwards? So if I have a string that contains apple, I can use this string to access the number zero from the array? Or in other words, is there a way to refer to a certain level of the array with a piece of data? I am working on much larger chunk of code that is a bit complex, and I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Loop through the array until you find it. Or change the array to a `List` and call [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: The right answer to your question depends on what you *really* need. I mean, why do you need the index? If it is because the index can be used to look up into other arrays of same size to get other information, then you're not using the Object Oriented features of Java, and the right answer might be to use a `Map<String, Fruit>`.

Comment: I have a two dimensional array that I am trying to populate with data. If a certain string is an apple, for instance, than I would want to fill in the same row as the index of the word apple in the array(so array[0][whatevercolumn]=whatever I want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would either need to search the list til you find the matching index, or else have some additional data structure in place to support the reverse mapping.

Comment: I figured this was the only way, I was just hoping that there was something stupid easy that I wasn't aware of. Thanks for the answer and for the edits  that you made on my question as well.